# Change navigation text color on scroll over sections with data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site with fullscreen image header sections (header data-attribute="image") and sections with a white background (no data-attribute). The default color of my nav (that has no background-color) is white. This is fine for when I scroll over images. But I would like to change the text-color (give a class ".black-text") of my navigation when I scroll over a header section with (data-attribute="image") and vice versa. The sections do not have fixed heights as the content of the sections can change.

This is my jQuery so far. Can this be done only with jQuery or do I need another JS plugin?

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    jQuery('header').each(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= jQuery(this).offset().top) {
            var image = jQuery(this).attr('*[data-type="image"]');
            jQuery('.site-header .navigation a').addClass('black-text');
        } else {
            jQuery('.site-header .navigation a').removeClass('black-text');
        }
    });
});
```